# Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'tasks' since it isn't a known property of 'task-list'

Tags: angular, storybook

I'm working on storybook and i have a problem regarding the binding to a property of 'task-list'.

Here is my code :

```
export const defaultTasks = [
  { ...task, id: '1', title: 'Task 1' },
  { ...task, id: '2', title: 'Task 2' },
];

const props = {
  tasks: defaultTasks,
  onPinTask: actions.onPinTask,
  onArchiveTask: actions.onArchiveTask,
};

storiesOf('TaskList', module)
  .addDecorator(
    moduleMetadata({
      declarations: [TaskListComponent, TaskComponent],
      imports: [CommonModule],
    }),
  )
  .add('default', () => {
    return {
      template: `
        <div style="padding: 3rem">
          <task-list [tasks]="tasks" (onPinTask)="onPinTask($event)" (onArchiveTask)="onArchiveTask($event)"></task-list>
        </div>
      `,
      props,
    };
  })
```

it should actually know it but i don't know why it's taken as it isn't a known property of 'task-list'

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your `TaskListComponent` does not have an `@Input() public tasks`

Comment: I just updated my question and added my TaskListComponent, i actually have tasks in there

Comment: @brxnzaz you forgot about `@Input` decorator

Comment: you need to declare that your tasks attribute is an input

Comment: this error seems to be comming from your TaskItemComponent. Try to do the same thing as in TaskListComponent

Comment: i already did, i didn't have a problem in there but still getting the same error

Comment: @brxnzaz, did you find a solution to that?
I also declared my variable with the @Input() decorator, but still facing the same problem as yours.
Any pointers to fix that?